# Using a switch with strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string, textarea, switch-statement

My `switch` statement is not working properly when analysing a string variable.

The output and input are both `<textarea>`'s.

**HTML**

```
<form name="interface">
  <textarea name="output" rows="20" cols="100"></textarea><br>
  <textarea name="input" rows="1" cols="100" onKeyDown="thinkInput(event);"></textarea>
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function thinkInput(e)
{
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {
        sInput = document.interface.input.value;
        document.interface.output.value += sInput;
        aInput = sInput.split(" ");

        switch (aInput[0])
        {
            case "say":
                textOut("You say \""+sInput.substring(aInput[0].length + 1)+"\"");
                break;
            case "move":
                move(aInput[1]);
                break;
            default:
                thinkFail();
                break;
        }
        document.interface.input.value = null;
        alert(aInput[0]);
    }
}
```

I can see in my `alert()` at the end that the case is either "say" or "move".

The first time I try to "say mudkipz" or "move around", everything works as I want it, but after that everything I type, `thinkFail()` fires.

Answer (score 2):

Your code isn't executing due to a new line that appears above the command prompt and the split array doesn't contain the reference first word on [0] value. Don't know why, even though you're clearing the value of input.

Since you'll be needing only one line on this input, I suggest using `<input type="text" onKeyDown="thinkInput(event);"/>` to avoid getting new lines on enter.

**JavaScript**

```
this.thinkInput = function (e)
{   
    ...

    if (e.keyCode == 13)
    {   
        /* Prevent submitting form on Enter */ 
        e.preventDefault();

        var command, commands;

        command = cmd.value;
        commands = command.split(' ');
        /* Clear input field */
        cmd.value = '';

        /* commands[0] will always have reference
           to the first word in textfield */
        switch (commands[0])
        {
            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a little fiddle I threw together from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/npx86/1/

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

One issue is that you are not using the `var` statement to define your variables. This means they become "implicit globals", and are kept through your different calls.

```
var sInput = document.interface.input.value;
var aInput = sInput.split(" ");
document.interface.output.value += sInput;
```

To further diagnose the problem, you can use the debugger tools in your browser to insert a breakpoint, and step through to monitor the value of `sInput` and to locate the problem.

Comment: sorry, i declared the variables before this function:
var sInput;
var aInput = new Array();

Comment: well checked your code and it actually works ... did a little modifications to work with jQuery: var sInput =$('#input').val();
$('#output').val($('#output').val() + sInput);
var aInput = sInput.split(" ");
switch (aInput[0])
{case "say": alert("You say \""+sInput.substring(aInput[0].length + 1)+"\"");
          break;
      case "move":
        alert(aInput[1]);
        break;
    default:
      alert("thinkFail");
         break;
  }
  $('#input').val('');}

Comment: thanks for the firebug thing, i've never heard of that before. i'll dl and try it when i get home :)

Comment: weird... why i tried it again it's not working on my laptop o.0;;

Comment: did my code worked before you changed it for jQuery? i don't know anything about jQuery XD I'm wondering if you fixed the problem when you changed it maybe.

Comment: well most likely something happens inside these methods textOut,move and declaring the variables outside the function will still make them global and persistent. again used your code this time after seeing the HTML and it sill works; I've just replaced those methods with alerts.

Comment: =)) I've got it. It's the <enter> you hit. you should cancel the bubble function thinkInput(e)
{
var ret = true;
if (e.keyCode == 13)
{
ret = false; ...} return ret;            and on onKeyDown="return thinkInput(event);">

Answer (score 0):

This happens because *after* resetting the `input` box value to empty, the pressed key (enter) gets added. This causes `aInput[0]` to start with a CR (which you wouldn't see in the `alert()` message.

You can easily fix this by trimming the left side of `sInput` before you split it:

```
aInput = sInput.replace(/^\s+/,'').split(" ");
```

Alternatively, you can cancel the `keydown` event by returning `false` explicitly from the function when `<CR>` is pressed and change the HTML to:

```
onkeydown="return thinkInput(event);"
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try any of these?

at the end

```
document.interface.input.value = "";
```

It really should be an empty string, as null + "hello" > "nullhello"

or at the start

```
document.interface.output.value = sInput;
```

Does it actually serve a purpose to add the string if you reset the output value each time?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something... when I'm looking/testing this code it runs every time the keydown event is triggered and because you are clearing the input field we are only working with single characters.

If I were to type "say" then the code would execute with "s", then 
"a", then "y".

If what you're wanting to do if scan the textarea for those words, I'd recommend pulling the value of `document.interface.output.value` and comparing that value against your case.

Hope this helps.

**EDIT:** Can you post your move method, textOut method and thinkFail method? From what I can tell if any exception is hit then that is when the case doesn't work. I created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HXwUH/9/) where it works fine.

Comment: Doesn't the 'if (e.keyCode == 13)' mean it only runs with carriage return?

Comment: @DavidSykes Thanks for pointing that out. I didn't look closely enough at this question. I'm going to revise my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Put this line before the switch
....

```
aInput = sInput.split(" ");
aInput[0] = aInput[0].replace(/\s/gi, "");

switch (aInput[0])
{
```

....

Or you can use  for the text input, instead of textarea.

Answer (score 0):

I know it has been a while since this was asked but I have to provide an answer anyway.

The reason your code is not working is that the input Textarea is not empty after the first try. The linebreak is still added to the textarea after the code is run and the next time you press enter it is the first char in the input.

If you either change the onKeyDown to onKeyUp or add a new eventHandler for onKeyUp to empty the input you should be fine.

```
<textarea name="input" rows="3" cols="100" onKeyUp="thinkInput(event);"></textarea>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/borglinm/ntj3t/1/